# Adding excel table to QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, excel, table, image

Can anyone suggest some ideas to add a excel table to the print composer which will then be exported as a A3 png while retaining resolution. Attempted pasting in word as an enhanced meta file then saving it as a png > adding to composer, also tried exporting the table as pdf then converting to SVG in Inkscape (which retains resolution / scalability but doesn't render text in columns correctly).

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Save your excel file as CSV file
2. go to `Add Vector Layer` in QGIS and navigate to your CSV file and
   load it
3. In the print composer, go to `Add attribute table`, as you can see below:

[image]

4. Select the `Source from Layer Feature` from the window in the right,as shown below:

[image]

5. You can change the font and formats based on your needs, and here is final output:

[image]

**UPDATE**

In **QGIS 2.14.3** there is an extra option (Advanced Customization) that you can change the background color of the header, rows (even OR odd), columns (even OR odd), as you can see in the image below

[image]

It will create something close to what you need

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good solution. It doesn't quite given me the result I need in terms of been able to customize how it looks though,e.g. different font colors for different items within the table etc. I'm also not able to resize it? Its fixed. Added example of table, to original question.

Comment: You can resize it using the cell margin, and you can change the header font as well as the font of items separately. I am using QGIS 2.8.9

Answer (score 1):

You mention you're using inkscape so you could try flipping your method round rather than doing it all in QGIS.  Have you tried exporting the composer to an SVG, open it into inkscape and then import the formatted table as a png?

Answer (score 1):

With the worksheet in Excel you can save to the WEB page where the form will generate a file in HTML format after you push the print composite through HTML frame icon.
Tip Select the worksheet and save only the selected area.

[image]

[image]