# Creating title blocks in QGIS

Tags: qgis, table

I am trying to create a table in composer to be positioned at the base of the map and is essentially a title block to provide information in text, image and table form. The only success I have had is creating many small text boxes and strategically placing them to appear as a table. However this is extremely tedious and if I need to change the spacing of 1, I need to then change the spacing's of all other text boxes- surely there is an easier solution.

Comment: like this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199418/adding-excel-table-to-qgis-print-composer

Comment: If @mapperz solution isn't what you want, please update your question with an image of the "title block" you're trying to create.

Comment: Welcome to GSE ! Don't forget to specify which version of software / tool you are using, tools or code are evoluting !

Answer (score 1):

I have previously (in my early days...) created simple title blocks using [HTML tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics), using the Add HTML tool and constructing the table from scratch using `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` etc., specifying most column widths and alignments in-line - a more sophisticated approach would heavily use the user stylesheet option to set certain defaults, and set up certain table style classes etc.

Then I would save the title block as a template by going to Layout > Save as Template, and using Layout Manager to create new maps from that template.

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

I think that might be the best option to create a table template, but be warned, it can be extremely time consuming, especially if you do not know much about HTML/CSS. Column widths, text padding, merged rows, font settings, etc.

Ideally, all of your text in the title block would be static or controlled by an attribute/variable as it is very inconvenient trying to replace/edit table contents in the HTML code, with the tiny text block provided - it's meant more for you to paste HTML that's ready to go.

---

Personally, I've since shifted to template styles that don't divide sections by lines at all, and just use text boxes with no frame for everything.

I lock the top-left coordinate of the text boxes (and sometimes the width) by going to Item Properties > Position and Size to prevent inadvertent shifting while allowing for some resizing. This still allows flexibility if needed, and is much easier and more user-friendly than modifying HTML. I also don't have to worry about shifting lines around.

If I really need a line to separate items I will just draw one using the Add Polyline tool in composer, and lock the polyline's location.

[image]